# how to customize audio recording quality in android?

Tags: android

I need to improve the quality of the audio recorder !! This is my code..pls help me out...

```
   mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();

    mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
    mRecorder.setOutputFile(mFileName);
    mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
    mRecorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate((int)(5.15 * 1024));
    mRecorder.setAudioSamplingRate(48000);
```

EDIT:

I have tried other applications, they have a higher quality output files....But my output accompanies lot of noises..

Comment: The quality of the recording depends on the mic's hardware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you getting noisy output files, then there must be any problem in your code.

In recording, audio quality depends on your mic hardware. And noisy output files shows while you writing the  byte array to FileOutputStream, there must be any problem.

Check that portion in your code.